# inital value of <mat-select>

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following. On the page load I am loading a default week for available dates. I want the mat-select to show the date loaded right now its blank until the user selects a different date. It works fine if I set to option.selectedID but I want to send the object in the handleselect($event). how can I display the inital value when the page loads.

````
       <mat-select
        
        (selectionChange)="handleSelect($event)"
      >
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of this.AvailableDates"
          [value]="option"
        >
          {{this.DisplayDate(option.date)}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>```
````

Comment: You can add ```[ngModel]``` and set its value in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[(ngModel)]** for mat-select:

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <mat-option value="1">One</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">Two</mat-option>
....
</mat-select>
```

Then set **selectedOption** equals to one of your mat-option value (Component.ts):

```
selectedOption = '1';
```